# How to hook to webpack-dev-server build?

Tags: git, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack and webpack-dev-server.

I want to display the `git describe` output on my html page.

Is there a way hook on webpack-dev-server rebuild, execute `git describe`, and put the output somewhere on the page?

Answer (score 4):

My solution: I wrote plugin for webpack

```
var GitDescribePlugin = function(/*options*/) {
};

GitDescribePlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
  compiler.plugin("compile", function(/*params*/) {
    console.log("The compiler is starting to compile...");
    child_process.execSync('git describe --always > gitdescribe.txt');
  });
};
```

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh The official doc https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-plugins.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are [using webpack with grunt](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-grunt.html), you can include the [`grunt-git-describe` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-git-describe).

That will allow you to include a `"git-describe" task` and or save its output:

```
grunt.registerTask('saveRevision', function() {
    grunt.event.once('git-describe', function (rev) {
        grunt.log.writeln("Git Revision: " + rev);
        grunt.option('gitRevision', rev);
    });    
    grunt.task.run('git-describe');
});
```